# How to display the 'Request New Password' page for Administrators.

Tags: 7, users

What I'd like to do is have the exact same page as /user/password (when not logged in)  that the 'Administrator' Role could use and send out emails to existing users.

However when logged in you get a 'Password reset instructions will be mailed to'  message.  I've had a hunt for a module or how to do it programmatically but can't find a solution.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think you'd need to do it with [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

Create a View (only accessible by the Admin role) which lists all the users, add VBO and I think reset password is included as one of the actions.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not quite the answer.  I should work with module Login One Time . However I can't get it to work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

The full answer .  Thanks to @colin_shipton

is I used Login One Time,  Views Bulk Operations and Views.

I had an issue getting Login One Time to work but the issue was actually with permissions not saving ( php.ini setting on local ) .  So once you've checked your permissions for Login One Time &  Views Bulk Operations everything should be fine.